# Simple way to increment a String containing a value eg: USER1000

Tags: java

I have :

```
String username = "USER1"
String username = "USER10000"
```

I want to increment the value like `USER2` OR `USER100001`

Is there a simple way to do it or should I loop trough the `String` and check for each characters if it is a digit and construct my new String.

Something like

```
for(int i=username.length()-1; i>0; i--) {
   if( !Character.isDigit(username.charAt(i) ) ){

        //creating new string here
   }

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

something like:

```
String un = "USER10000";
int digit = Integer.parseInt( un.replaceAll( "\\D", "" ) );
String newUn = "USER" + ( digit + 1 );
```

you can use `long` if more appropriate.

UPDATE:

`"\\D"` can be also rewritten as `"[^\\d]"`, as they are matching the same charachters

Comment: Dind't you want to say `"[^\\d]"` ?

Comment: I love stackoverflow :) thank you. Could you update your answer with `"[^\\d]"` I will use `Long` in a positive way of thinking :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it old-school:

```
String increment(String s) {
    char[] a = s.toCharArray();
    boolean incremented = false;
    for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0 && !incremented; i--) {
        if (Character.isDigit(a[i])) {
            if (a[i] == '9') {
                a[i] = '0';
            } else {
                a[i] = (char) (a[i] + 1);
                incremented = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!incremented) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to increment " + s);
    }
    return new String(a);
}
```

Comment: fails with `"USER9"` because `incremented` is not set to true, also it doesnt make of a n-digits number an n+1-digits number, for example 9 -> 10

Comment: @A4L - Correct! This is an edge-case that OP did not cover so I made it an Exception. This can handle leading zeros though, unlike the other solution.

Comment: I think he did since he gave as first example `"USER1` should be incremented to `"USER2"`, and continuing from that value `"USER9"` will come at some point, just saying...